# What are approaches to calling gcp APIs from terraform? For ex, creating GCP pubsub Snapshot

Tags: rest, terraform, google-cloud-pubsub, snapshot, terraform-provider-gcp

I want to create [snapshot](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/pubsub/snapshots/create), which is currently not available through GCP Terraform provider. So I want to be able to use the `snapshot` [API call](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.snapshots/create) to achieve this. Once the snapshot is created, I need to call some external APIs as well, for instance call the remote server endpoint to restart the service.

What are the standard / better approaches with Terraform to do this? I am newbie with terraform. So no idea how to approach this.

Comment: E.g. null_resource

Comment: How does that help with the what I need to get done?

Comment: By running whatever command / code / script from there: https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/resources/provisioners/local-exec.html

Comment: But question is about what is the standard way to do that? create `module`? or `provider`? `local-exec` etc are called only once, when newly setting up or when destroying, it does not run every time, when we `apply`

Comment: Please consider accepting an answer if one has been helpful. See [how does accepting an answer work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to start using null_resources or calling scripts from Terraform if you can at all help it. You'd only want to use a local-exec/remote-exec where you really can't architect a proper solution.

One alternative is to wrap this up in a [Cloud Function](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/cloudfunctions_function) and apply a [cron trigger](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/cloud_scheduler_job) to it if the snapshotting is predictable.

Alternatively you could also wrap it all up in a [Workflow](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/workflows_workflow).